# Replace NULL values in query with values of another row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

How can I replace all `null` values in the result set with values from another row of the same table? (like a fallback query)

Example schema:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    int1 INTEGER,
    int2 INTEGER,
    int3 INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id = ?
```

But I need to replace all `null` values with those of another row. I am looking for something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = ?
   REPLACE ALL NULL VALUES WITH (
       SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = ?
   )
```

Example:

```
id    int1    int2   int3
---------------------------
 1     1      null    1
 2     null   null    1
 3     1       4      0
```

When I query for id 1 first and id 3 as fallback, I expect the result to be:

```
id    int1   int2   int3
---------------------------
 1     1      4      1
```

Comment: Could a `CASE` statement help you?

Comment: I don't know, that's the reason I asked ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select t1.id,
       coalesce(t1.int1, tt1.int1) as int1,
       coalesce(t1.int2, tt1.int2) as int2,
       coalesce(t1.int3, tt1.int3) as int3
from table1 t1 join
     table1 tt1
     on tt1.id = 3
where t1.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

join and [ISNULL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)() (for MS SQL and IFNULL for MySql) function will be helpful in this case:

```
select t1.id, ISNULL(main.int1, fallback.int1) as int1,
       ISNULL(main.int2, fallback.int2) as int2,
       ISNULL(main.int3, fallback.int3) as int3
from table1 as main join table1 as fallback on fallback.id = 3
where main.id = 1;
```

Comment: As far as I know isnull does not exist for MySQL. It is an MS SQL function.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [case](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case.html).

```
select case mycolumn is null
       when 1 then myothercolumn
       else mycolumn
       end
from mytable
```

You can also embed `case`-`when` into another. This should be sufficient for you to solve the problem.